# BeforeSend for jquery .load()

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is it possible to set the execution of some code immediately after an initiation of ajax by `.load() function`,  before sending the request to server? I need it to add `xhr` to `array`, to have an ability to abort all of `xhr` pool.

If it's not possible, and I should replace `.load ()` by `$.ajax()`.

is it possible to load not the whole html, but the part of it, like what `.load()` does?

Comment: `.load()` does not partially load the response. It's basically the equivalent of `$.get(url).done(html => $(this).html(html))` with some slight differences if you supply data (becomes a POST) or specify a selector (will search the HTML response and only inject the found element)

Comment: I trust you've read the documentation for [.ajaxSend()](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/)? Seems to be what you're after as far as global config goes

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems like `.ajaxSend()` is exactly what I was looking for. Later I will try and add one more comment with feedback.

Comment: It works exactly the way I wanted. Thanks again! By the way I found there alot of other useful global ajax event handlers.